# Adding azoom effect to an ImageView like gallery images

Tags: android, zooming, android-gallery

I have many images made with viewpager and picasso. i want to implement zoom effect in all of those images.

I mean when we doubleclick/expand finger the photo in gallery app and again doubleclick or by pinching finger the photo come in its own position.

I want to implement that methods. I watched/read many but couln't find the solution that works for all of my images made with picasso and viewpager.

And the method should be compatible from API 19

This is mainactivty.javawhere pictures are shown:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;

    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{
            R.raw.oooo,
            R.raw.o8,
            R.raw.oa,
            R.raw.oad,
            R.raw.oap,
            R.raw.ok,
            //there are many others
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is ViewPagerAdapter:

```java
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int[] imageUrls;

    ViewPageAdapter(Context context, int[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                    Picasso.get()
                    .load(imageUrls[position])
                    .resize(400, 400)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
            container.addView(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: This library is good for zooming images https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom ImageView. I found this useful.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2012-2013 Jeremie Martinez (jeremiemartinez@gmail.com)
 * <p>
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 * <p>
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * <p>
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;

/**
 * @author jmartinez
 *
 *         Simple Android ImageView that enables dragging and zooming.
 *
 */
public class ZoomableImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private float maxScale = 3f;
    private float minScale = 1f;

    private enum State {
        INIT, DRAG, ZOOM
    }

    private State state;

    private Matrix matrix;
    private float[] finalTransformation = new float[9];
    private PointF last = new PointF();
    private float currentScale = 1f;

    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private float afterScaleDrawableWidth;
    private float afterScaleDrawableHeight;

    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;

    private GestureDetector doubleTapDetecture;

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setUp(context);
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setUp(context);
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setUp(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        // Set up drawable at first load
        if (hasDrawable()) {
            resetImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        doubleTapDetecture.onTouchEvent(event);

        PointF current = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(current);
                state = State.DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (state == State.DRAG) {
                    drag(current);
                    last.set(current);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                state = State.INIT;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                state = State.INIT;
                break;
        }

        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set up the class. Method called by constructors.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private void setUp(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(false);
        matrix = new Matrix();
        state = State.INIT;
        scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        doubleTapDetecture = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    private void resetImage() {

        // Scale Image
        float scale = getScaleForDrawable();
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center Image
        float marginY = ((float) viewHeight - (scale * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight())) / 2;
        float marginX = ((float) viewWidth - (scale * getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth())) / 2;
        matrix.postTranslate(marginX, marginY);

        afterScaleDrawableWidth = (float) viewWidth - 2 * marginX;
        afterScaleDrawableHeight = (float) viewHeight - 2 * marginY;

        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

    /**
     * Getter and setter for max/min scale. Default are min=1 and max=3
     */

    public float getMaxScale() {
        return maxScale;
    }

    public void setMaxScale(float maxScale) {
        this.maxScale = maxScale;
    }

    public float getMinScale() {
        return minScale;
    }

    public void setMinScale(float minScale) {
        this.minScale = minScale;
    }

    /**
     * Drag method
     *
     * @param current
     *            Current point to drag to.
     */
    private void drag(PointF current) {
        float deltaX = getMoveDraggingDelta(current.x - last.x, viewWidth, afterScaleDrawableWidth * currentScale);
        float deltaY = getMoveDraggingDelta(current.y - last.y, viewHeight, afterScaleDrawableHeight * currentScale);
        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
        limitDrag();
    }

    /**
     * Scale method for zooming
     *
     * @param focusX
     *            X of center of scale
     * @param focusY
     *            Y of center of scale
     * @param scaleFactor
     *            scale factor to zoom in/out
     */
    private void scale(float focusX, float focusY, float scaleFactor) {
        float lastScale = currentScale;
        float newScale = lastScale * scaleFactor;

        // Calculate next scale with resetting to max or min if required
        if (newScale > maxScale) {
            currentScale = maxScale;
            scaleFactor = maxScale / lastScale;
        } else if (newScale < minScale) {
            currentScale = minScale;
            scaleFactor = minScale / lastScale;
        } else {
            currentScale = newScale;
        }

        // Do scale
        if (requireCentering()) {
            matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, (float) viewWidth / 2, (float) viewHeight / 2);
        } else
            matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, focusX, focusY);

        limitDrag();
    }

    /**
     * This method permits to keep drag and zoom inside the drawable. It makes sure the drag is staying in bound.
     */
    private void limitDrag() {
        matrix.getValues(finalTransformation);
        float finalXTransformation = finalTransformation[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float finalYTransformation = finalTransformation[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float deltaX = getScaleDraggingDelta(finalXTransformation, viewWidth, afterScaleDrawableWidth * currentScale);
        float deltaY = getScaleDraggingDelta(finalYTransformation, viewHeight, afterScaleDrawableHeight * currentScale);

        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
    }

    private float getScaleDraggingDelta(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans = 0;
        float maxTrans = 0;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        }

        if (delta < minTrans)
            return minTrans - delta;
        else if (delta > maxTrans)
            return maxTrans - delta;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    // Check if dragging is still possible if so return delta otherwise return 0 (do nothing)
    private float getMoveDraggingDelta(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    private float getScaleForDrawable() {
        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        return Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    }

    private boolean hasDrawable() {
        return getDrawable() != null && getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() != 0 && getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() != 0;
    }

    private boolean requireCentering() {
        return afterScaleDrawableWidth * currentScale <= (float) viewWidth || afterScaleDrawableHeight * currentScale <= (float) viewHeight;
    }

    private boolean isZoom() {
        return currentScale != 1f;
    }

    /**
     * Listener for detecting scale.
     *
     * @author jmartinez
     */
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            state = State.ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scale(detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY(), detector.getScaleFactor());
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener for double tap detection
     *
     * @author jmartinez
     */
    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            if (isZoom()) {
                resetImage();
                currentScale = 1f;
                state = State.INIT;

            } else {
                scale(e.getX(), e.getY(), maxScale);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Then instead of ImageView you can use ...yourpackage.ZoomableImageView

Comment: I have shown image by viewPager and if i replaced with yourpackage.ZoomableImageView then project is gone. ???

Comment: You need to create a new class ZoomableImageView. Then you can add this to your XML layout. yourpackage should be your project package name. Which usually starts like com.test.blablabla....

Comment: oh! can you please say me how can I add ZoomableImageView in XML? please?

Comment: Did you add the class? If yes then on the XML start typing ZoomableImageView 

<..ZoomableImageView....

Comment: I added ZoomableImageView  class and wrap it into viewPager like this:
```java
<com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.ZoomableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent />
    </com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.ZoomableImageView>
```

Comment: but while running app, it suddenly close itself please help me @ArbenMaloku

Comment: You also need to change your adapter. 
Change

 ImageView imageView = new ZoomableImageView(context);

to 

  ZoomableImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

Comment: where I have written ImageView imageView = new ZoomableImageView(context);  to change it? :( @ArbenMaloku

Comment: Yes, you must change it!!

Comment: OMG, It worked thank you very much @ArbenMaloku. It worked. :). Thanks for answering my stupid answers. :)

First of all, I replaced imageView with com....Zoom.. and replace ImageView to ZoomableImageView in the adapter and it worked. 

At first, I was confused so... Anyway thanks.